# How to insert html tool-tip into Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

I tried following the documentation like this:

```
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Month');
data.addColumn('number', "Total Donation Ratio");
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html:true}});
data.addColumn('number', "Total Trophies");
data.addRows([
[new Date(2016, 1, 21, 0, 53), 0.4042, '<ul class="google-visualization-tooltip-item-list"><li class="google-visualization-tooltip-item><span style="font-weight:bold;">21 Feb,2016, 12:02 AM</span></li>
<li class="google-visualization-tooltip-item>Total Donation Ratio: <span style="font-weight:bold;">0.4042</span></li>
<li class="google-visualization-tooltip-item><span style="font-weight:bold;">Donated:0</span></li>
</ul>', 46805], AND_SO_ON....
```

with

```
 var classicOptions = {
        tooltip: {isHtml: true},
```

but it fails to load and i get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in my console.

What am i doing wrong?

Is there away just to add extra html to the default tooltip rather then having to do it as the above way? because i would like the keep the default css styling.

Comment: `var classicOptions = { ... etc` ... that's not a complete object ... is that the whole code

Comment: Not it's not the whole code but i have proper closing tags in the whole code

Comment: sorry, the error suggested otherwise ... that error must point to a line of code ... what's the line of code with the error (and the previous/next lines for context)

Comment: its pointing to where the html codes start `[new Date(2016, 1, 21, 0, 53), 0.4042, '<ul class="google-visualization-tooltip-item-list"><li class="google-visualization-tooltip-item><span style="font-weight:bold;">21 Feb,2016, 12:02 AM</span></li>
`